# Create a media query to display Page Zoom 90%

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have designed a site that displays better at 90% zoom. I'm wondering if there's anyway to pull the styles from my browser and add these to a new media query.

Unfortunately I haven't designed my site to use EM and % definitively, so changing the body size wont work. I foresee me having to go through the styles and either change the values to meet the 90% or convert all to em/%.

So my question is; when a browser is displaying at 90% zoom. Can these styles be pulled from the browser, or is there any method to easily convert or obtain these values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that the browser can provide you with the zoomed values, since the zooming as far as I know is "on top" of the styling engine. You can see that by looking at the calculated dimensions of an element in the browser's development tools. They don't change depending on the zoom level.

What you could try is use a [CSS transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale):

```
body {
  transform: scale(.9);
}
```

However this won't necessarily the identical to the browser zoom, since they work differently.